# how to skip registry scan, if root key is not available

Tags: c#, registry

I have a root folder in registry name `MyApp`, inside we have many entries like below. I need to go to each sub entries and get some registry data.

```
var registryValue = GetRegistryValue(managementScope, "SOFTWARE\\MyApp\\app1", "Version", ipAdd, username, password);
var registryValue = GetRegistryValue(managementScope, "SOFTWARE\\MyApp\\app2", "Version", ipAdd, username, password);
var registryValue = GetRegistryValue(managementScope, "SOFTWARE\\MyApp\\app3", "Version", ipAdd, username, password);
```

Supported methods to get registry value using `WMI`,

```
public static string GetRegistryValue(ManagementScope managementScope, string subRegistryPath, string subRegistryKey, string assetNameOrIpAddress, string username, string password)
    {
        string value = string.Empty;

        //get the value from default view
        object registryValue = GetValue(managementScope, subRegistryPath, subRegistryKey);

        if (registryValue != null)
        {
            value = registryValue.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            //change the registry view to 64
            managementScope.Options.Context.Add("__ProviderArchitecture", 64);
            managementScope.Options.Context.Add("__RequiredArchitecture", true);

            //again try to get the value 
            registryValue = GetValue(managementScope, subRegistryPath, subRegistryKey);

            if (registryValue != null)
            {
                value = registryValue.ToString();
            }
        }

        return value;
    }

    private static object GetValue(ManagementScope managementScope, string subKeyName, string valueName)
    {

        using (ManagementClass registry = new ManagementClass(managementScope, new ManagementPath("StdRegProv"), null))
        {
            ManagementBaseObject inParams = registry.GetMethodParameters("GetStringValue");
            inParams["sSubKeyName"] = subKeyName;
            inParams["sValueName"] = valueName;
            return registry.InvokeMethod("GetStringValue", inParams, null).Properties["sValue"].Value;
        }
    }
```

What I want to check first if root registry name `MyApp` is NOT available, the  I want to discard all my sub key registry call. Is this possible?

When I am doing `GetRegistryValue(managementScope, "SOFTWARE", "MyApp", ipAdd, username, password)`, I'm getting empty value, even the root registry entry `MyApp` is available for machine. Whats wrong here?

```
if(GetRegistryValue(managementScope, "SOFTWARE", "MyApp", ipAdd, username, password) is available)
then 
var registryValue = GetRegistryValue(managementScope, "SOFTWARE\\MyApp\\app1", "Version", ipAdd, username, password);
var registryValue = GetRegistryValue(managementScope, "SOFTWARE\\MyApp\\app2", "Version", ipAdd, username, password);
var registryValue = GetRegistryValue(managementScope, "SOFTWARE\\MyApp\\app3", "Version", ipAdd, username, password);
```

Comment: Call .OpenSubKey on "SOFTWARE\MyApp", if its null the key does not exist, if its not null use the return value to read its subkeys

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question and supplied method to get registry value. When I am doing `GetRegistryValue(managementScope, "SOFTWARE", "MyApp", ipAdd, username, password) `, I'm getting blank value even the root registry entry `MyApp` is available for machine